# Remove all elements contained in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for an efficient way to remove all elements from a javascript array if they are present in another array.

```
// If I have this array:
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

// and this one:
var toRemove = ['b', 'c', 'g'];
```

I want to operate on myArray to leave it in this state: `['a', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

With jQuery, I'm using `grep()` and `inArray()`, which works well:

```
myArray = $.grep(myArray, function(value) {
    return $.inArray(value, toRemove) < 0;
});
```

Is there a pure javascript way to do this without looping and splicing?

Comment: No matter what, it'll always involve looping at some level.

Comment: If you genuinely want it to be "efficient", you won't use functional type methods like `.filter()`. Instead you'll use `for` loops. You can avoid `.splice()` if the original order doesn't need to be maintained. Or there are ways to make `.splice()` more efficient if you think there will be many items to remove.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

Use the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
myArray = myArray.filter( function( el ) {
  return toRemove.indexOf( el ) < 0;
} );
```

---

Small improvement, as browser support for [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) has increased:

```js
myArray = myArray.filter( function( el ) {
  return !toRemove.includes( el );
} );
```

---

Next adaptation using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
myArray = myArray.filter( ( el ) => !toRemove.includes( el ) );
```

Comment: OP: If you're using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) there's [`.difference()`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) which basically does this.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thank you.  @BillCriswell, I will check out underscore.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting different results from you guys, but in my case the function in filter is actually `function(index, el)` not `function(el)`.

Comment: @Floss the first parameter to `filter()` is the element according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: How would you make this case insensitive?

Comment: @AlecRust Convert all elements of `toRemove()` to upper case and change in the callback from `el` to `el.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: For some reason when I call any of the three functions they never seem to end.

Comment: isn't this order n^2?

Comment: @FrazerKirkman As usual in not performance critical environments or only small problem instances I prefer readability of code over (micro-)optimization. But you're right, that this is suboptimal. From the top of my head I can think of at least an `O( n * log n)` algorithm for that.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this in order of n ?

Comment: @PraveenKishor getting it down to `O(n)` without any prior assumptions on the input data is not possible, from my current understanding. If the data is sorted previously, then this assumption, e.g., would get you to that point.

Comment: I tried the latest solution in NodeJS and it didn't work. I had to replace `( el ) => !toRemove.includes( el )` by `( el ) => { return !toRemove.includes( el ) }` . (I added brackets and 'return' keywork)

Comment: @PraveenKishor, you could make a newArray, and an object indexing the values of everything in toRemove.  Then loop over myArray;  ForEach value, if it is in not in your index object, push it to newArray.

Comment: This doesn't work for this code `let df = [ {'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }]
let nfl = [ {'name': 'A' },{'name': 'B' },{'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }]
let res = nfl.filter(x => df.indexOf(x)<0)` . Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: @GopalMishra your using objects and not primitives as in the example. in your example there are 6 different objects - that some of them look similar does not matter in this case - they still are different objects

Comment: Yes, It took me some time to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Could I please just comment a big THANK YOU for sharing this with us. you guys are so awesome!

Answer (score 99):

[ECMAScript 6 sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can permit faster computing of the elements of one array that aren't in the other:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const toRemove = new Set(['b', 'c', 'g']);

const difference = myArray.filter( x => !toRemove.has(x) );

console.log(difference); // ["a", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Since the [lookup complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation) for the V8 engine browsers use these days is O(1), the time complexity of the whole algorithm is O(n).

Comment: This is very very quick compared to using an Array with `.includes`. For large Arrays (~50,000), it went from about 79 seconds to under 1 second. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 75):

```
var myArray = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}, 
  {name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'}
];
var toRemove = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}
];



myArray = myArray.filter(ar => !toRemove.find(rm => (rm.name === ar.name && ar.place === rm.place) ))
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some explanation on such a well received question, please?

Comment: I searched hours for solution for the problem and just found it, just awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: You helped me complete my jira in 1 day thanks buddy

Comment: This is useful for array of objects with a unique attribute. +1

Comment: instead of `find()` I would use `some()`, which returns a boolean value instead of the matching item which then has to be asserted to be truthy or falsy to satisfy what `filter()` expects from its predicate argument.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, tyvm!

Comment: I have added an explanation to this in my answer below. @harmonica141

Answer (score 43):

The `filter` method should do the trick:

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const toRemove = ['b', 'c', 'g'];

// ES5 syntax
const filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(x) { 
  return toRemove.indexOf(x) < 0;
});
```

If your `toRemove` array is large, this sort of lookup pattern can be inefficient. It would be more performant to create a map so that lookups are `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

```
const toRemoveMap = toRemove.reduce(
  function(memo, item) {
    memo[item] = memo[item] || true;
    return memo;
  },
  {} // initialize an empty object
);

const filteredArray = myArray.filter(function (x) {
  return toRemoveMap[x];
});

// or, if you want to use ES6-style arrow syntax:
const toRemoveMap = toRemove.reduce((memo, item) => ({
  ...memo,
  [item]: true
}), {});

const filteredArray = myArray.filter(x => toRemoveMap[x]);
```

Comment: I really love this answer... I am just going to point in the last line that should return


const filteredArray = myArray.filter(x => !toRemoveMap[x]); // instead of toRemoveMap[x]

Answer (score 28):

If you are using an array of objects. Then the below code should do the magic, where an object property will be the criteria to remove duplicate items.

In the below example, duplicates have been removed comparing name of each item.

Try this example. http://jsfiddle.net/deepak7641/zLj133rh/

```js
var myArray = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}, 
  {name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'}
];
var toRemove = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}
];

for( var i=myArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
  for( var j=0; j<toRemove.length; j++){
      if(myArray[i] && (myArray[i].name === toRemove[j].name)){
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
     }
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Answer (score 15):

Lodash has an utility function for this as well:
https://lodash.com/docs#difference

Answer (score 15):

How about the simplest possible:

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var toRemove = ['b', 'c', 'g'];

var myArray = myArray.filter((item) => !toRemove.includes(item));
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `includes` is not available before ES7.

Answer (score 10):

I just implemented as:

```
Array.prototype.exclude = function(list){
        return this.filter(function(el){return list.indexOf(el)<0;})
}
```

Use as:

```
myArray.exclude(toRemove);
```

Comment: It is not good practice to extend `prototypes` of native Objects, such `Array`. That can have a long term conflict with future development of the language ( [see the `flatten` case](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56) )

Answer (score 8):

If you cannot use new ES5 stuff such `filter` I think you're stuck with two loops:

```
for( var i =myArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
  for( var j=0; j<toRemove.length; j++){
    if(myArray[i] === toRemove[j]){
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: filter isn't "new HTML5 stuff"

Comment: I should have written "ES5 stuff". It wasn't available with ES3

Answer (score 8):

You can use [_.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#difference) from lodash

```
const myArray = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}, 
  {name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'}
];
const toRemove = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}
];
const sorted = _.differenceBy(myArray, toRemove, 'name');
```

Example code here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMObZP?editors=1111)

Comment: What if the attribute is nested inside the object? Something test like in your case
{name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore' , nested : { test : 1}}

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty late but adding this to explain what `@mojtaba roohi` has answered. The first block of code will not work as each array is having a different object, i.e. df[0] != nfl[2]. Both objects look similar but are altogether different, which is not the case when we use primitive types like numbers.

```js
let df = [ {'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }] 
let nfl = [ {'name': 'A' },{'name': 'B' },{'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }] 
let res = nfl.filter(x => df.indexOf(x)<0)
console.log(res)
```

Here is the working code:

```js
let df = [{'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }]
let nfl = [ {'name': 'A' },{'name': 'B' },{'name': 'C' },{'name': 'D' }];
let res = nfl.filter((o1) => !df.some((o2) => o1.name === o2.name));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 5):

Now in one-liner flavor:

```js
console.log(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'].filter(x => !~['b', 'c', 'g'].indexOf(x)))
```

Might not work on old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Typescript and want to match on a single property value, this should work based on [Craciun Ciprian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172243/6846692) above.

You could also make this more generic by allowing non-object matching and / or multi-property value matching.

```
/**
 *
 * @param arr1 The initial array
 * @param arr2 The array to remove
 * @param propertyName the key of the object to match on
 */
function differenceByPropVal<T>(arr1: T[], arr2: T[], propertyName: string): T[] {
  return arr1.filter(
    (a: T): boolean =>
      !arr2.find((b: T): boolean => b[propertyName] === a[propertyName])
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## A High performance and immutable solution

### Javascript

```
const excludeFromArr = (arr, exclude) => {
  const excludeMap = exclude.reduce((all, item) => ({ ...all, [item]: true }), {});
  return arr.filter((item) => !excludeMap?.[item]);
};
```

### Typescript:

```js
const excludeFromArr = (arr: string[], exclude: string[]): string[] => {
  const excludeMap = exclude.reduce<Record<string, boolean>>((all, item) => ({ ...all, [item]: true }), {});
  return arr.filter((item) => !excludeMap?.[item]);
};
```

Comment: What makes this solution high-performance?

Comment: `#reduce` is slower than `#includes` that is a **native** method, at the point that the theoretical complexity O(1) over O(n), where `n = excludedMap.length`, doesn't matter. On contrary, it should be way worst than any other counterparts presented in other answers: `#includes`, `#indexOf`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to remove all elements contained in another array is to make source array same object by remove only elements:

```
Array.prototype.removeContained = function(array) {
  var i, results;
  i = this.length;
  results = [];
  while (i--) {
    if (array.indexOf(this[i]) !== -1) {
      results.push(this.splice(i, 1));
    }
  }
  return results;
};
```

Or CoffeeScript equivalent:

```
Array.prototype.removeContained = (array) ->
  i = @length
  @splice i, 1 while i-- when array.indexOf(@[i]) isnt -1
```

Testing inside chrome dev tools:

> 19:33:04.447 a=1
> 19:33:06.354 b=2
> 19:33:07.615 c=3
> 19:33:09.981 arr = [a,b,c]
> 19:33:16.460 arr1 = arr
>
> 19:33:20.317 arr1 === arr
> 19:33:20.331 true
>
> 19:33:43.592 **arr.removeContained([a,c])**
> 19:33:52.433 **arr === arr1**
> 19:33:52.438 **true**

Using Angular framework is the best way to keep pointer to source object when you update collections without large amount of watchers and reloads.

Comment: This answer is bad as it voids best practices. Specifically, never modifying objects you don't own. In this case, you're modifying the Array object, which is a big no-no.

Answer (score 0):

I build the logic without using any built-in methods, please let me know any optimization or modifications.
I tested in JS editor it is working fine.

```
var myArray = [
            {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
            {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'},
            {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'},
            {name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'},

        ];
        var toRemove = [

            {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'},
            {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
            /*{name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'},*/
            /*{name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'},*/


        ];
        var tempArr = [];
        for( var i=0 ; i < myArray.length; i++){
            for( var j=0; j<toRemove.length; j++){
                var toRemoveObj = toRemove[j];
                if(myArray[i] && (myArray[i].name === toRemove[j].name)) {
                    break;
                }else if(myArray[i] && (myArray[i].name !== toRemove[j].name)){
                        var fnd = isExists(tempArr,myArray[i]);
                        if(!fnd){
                            var idx = getIdex(toRemove,myArray[i])
                            if (idx === -1){
                                tempArr.push(myArray[i]);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
        }
        function isExists(source,item){
            var isFound = false;
            for( var i=0 ; i < source.length; i++){
                var obj = source[i];
                if(item && obj && obj.name === item.name){
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return isFound;
        }
        function getIdex(toRemove,item){
            var idex = -1;
            for( var i=0 ; i < toRemove.length; i++){
                var rObj =toRemove[i];
                if(rObj && item && rObj.name === item.name){
                    idex=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return idex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Using the new ES6 Syntax

    console.log(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"].filter(el => !["b", "c", "g"].includes(el)));

    // OR

    // Main array
    let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

    // Array to remove
    const toRemove = ["b", "c", "g"];

    const diff = () => (myArray = myArray.filter((el) => !toRemove.includes(el)));
  console.log(diff()); // [ 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]

    // OR

    const diff2 = () => {
      return myArray = myArray.filter((el) => !toRemove.includes(el));
    };
    console.log(diff2()); // [ 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
```