# Javascript - delete array from array

Tags: javascript, math

I want to delete elements from array in array (can't remember how it is named in math), for example:

```
var arr1 = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'],
    arr2 = ['dos', 'cuatro'],
    arr3 = arr1.without(arr2);
//arr3 === ['uno', 'tres']
```

Greetings

Comment: It's named as matrix in math

Comment: `arr3 = arr1.filter( item => !arr2.includes(item) )`

Comment: I think this kinda duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/javascript-arrays-remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array

Comment: I think the math term that you are looking for is called 'set difference'.

Answer (score 3):

`Array#filter` may be helpful.

```js
var arr1 = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'],
    arr2 = ['dos', 'cuatro'],
    arr3 = arr1.filter(v => arr2.indexOf(v) == -1);
    
    console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: I hoped there is some native function for it, but thanks!

Comment: @JimiAlvaro Native function? `Array#filter` is definetely native (:

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr1 = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];
var arr2 = ['dos', 'cuatro'];

arr1 = arr1.filter(function(item){
  return arr2.indexOf(item) < 0;
});
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and take the negated result.

```js
var arr1 = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'],
    arr2 = ['dos', 'cuatro'],
    arr3 = arr1.filter(v => !arr2.includes(v));
    
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, a ready function for that:

```
function substractArrays (arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr2.length) {
      return arr1.filter(item => {
        return !arr2.some(elem => {
          return item.id === elem.id;
        });
      });
    } else {
      return arr1;
    }
}
```