# Subtracts values one list from another in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove all values from `var a = [1,2,2,2,3]` which are present in `var b=[2]`If a values is present in b variable all of its occurrences must be remove

```
 var a = [1,2,2,2,5];
 var b = [2];
 const result = a.filter(function(el){

  return /// which condition .?

 });
```

How to remove the b var value. and we have many logics please answer it briefly

Comment: Use array filter

Comment: please add the wanted result - and what you have tried.

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript arrays: remove all elements contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/javascript-arrays-remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and check if the value exists using [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5];
var b = [2];

var result = a.filter(function(n) {
  return b.indexOf(n) === -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

However, this requires redundant iterations of the 2nd array. A better solution is to create a dictionary object from `b` using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and use it in the filtering:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5];
var b = [2];
var bDict = b.reduce(function(d, n) {
  d[n] = true;
  
  return d;
}, Object.create(null));

var result = a.filter(function(n) {
  return !bDict[n];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the unwanted items.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5],
    b = [2],
    result = a.filter((s => v => !s.has(v))(new Set(b)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following by using array's `filter()`:

```js
var a = [1,2,2,2,5];
var b = [2];
var c = a.filter(item => !b.includes(item))
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

use array.filter

```js
var first = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5];
var second = [2];

var result = first.filter(function(n) {
  return second.indexOf(n) === -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var a = [1,2,2,2,5];
 var b = [2];
var result= a.filter(function(x) { 
  return b.indexOf(x) < 0;
});
console.log(result)
```