# filtering in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are 2 arrays `tooarray` and `moarray` what I want is list of all elements which are in `moarray` but not in `tooarray`.

```
var tooarray = [ 
  { catalogue_id: 23480,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Other' 
  },
{ catalogue_id: 23481,
  parent_category_id: 23479,
  user_id: 28434,
  form_id: 4261,
  name: 'Tincture',
  description: 'Tincture'
},
{ catalogue_id: 23482,
  parent_category_id: 23479,
  user_id: 28434,
  form_id: 4261,
  name: 'Cannabis',
  description: 'Cannabis'
 },
 ]


var moarray = [ 
  'wedwewdwe',
  'Other',
  'Tincture',
  'Cannabis'
  ];

 var tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x =>{
            tooarray.filter(y=>{
              return x.indexOf(y.name) < 0;
            })
    });
```

**output recieving**

```
  tInsertArray []
```

**output expected**

```
tInsertArray [wedwewdwe]
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: i do not get expected output @NinaScholz

Comment: and what do you get?

Comment: [] array @NinaScholz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript arrays: remove all elements contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/javascript-arrays-remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array)

Comment: `let tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x => !tooarray.filter(y => y.name === x).length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter all elements from `moarray` where there is no element in `tooarray` that has `name` property equal to each `moarray` entry:

```js
let tooarray = [{
    catalogue_id: 23480,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Other'
  },
  {
    catalogue_id: 23481,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Tincture',
    description: 'Tincture'
  },
  {
    catalogue_id: 23482,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Cannabis',
    description: 'Cannabis'
  },
]

let moarray = [
  'wedwewdwe',
  'Other',
  'Tincture',
  'Cannabis'
];

let tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x => !tooarray.filter(y => y.name === x).length)

console.log(tInsertArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `find`

```js
var tooarray = [{
    catalogue_id: 23480,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Other'
  },
  {
    catalogue_id: 23481,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Tincture',
    description: 'Tincture'
  },
  {
    catalogue_id: 23482,
    parent_category_id: 23479,
    user_id: 28434,
    form_id: 4261,
    name: 'Cannabis',
    description: 'Cannabis'
  },
]


var moarray = [
  'wedwewdwe',
  'Other',
  'Tincture',
  'Cannabis'
];

var tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x => !tooarray.find(e => e.name === x));

console.log( tInsertArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the names and then do the filter

```
var tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x => {
    return tooarray.map(y => y.name).includes(x) === false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no `return` in first callback. That's why array comes empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with a check if the name exists.

```js
var tooarray = [{ catalogue_id: 23480, parent_category_id: 23479, user_id: 28434, form_id: 4261, name: 'Other' }, { catalogue_id: 23481, parent_category_id: 23479, user_id: 28434, form_id: 4261, name: 'Tincture', description: 'Tincture' }, { catalogue_id: 23482, parent_category_id: 23479, user_id: 28434, form_id: 4261, name: 'Cannabis', description: 'Cannabis' }],
    moarray = ['wedwewdwe', 'Other', 'Tincture', 'Cannabis'],
    tInsertArray = moarray.filter(x => !tooarray.some(({ name }) => name === x));

console.log(tInsertArray);
```