# Cannot remove duplicated item

Tags: javascript

I have these two arrays:

**original**

```
[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
```

**old**

```
[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "7"},
   { id: "9"}
]
```

I'm trying to remove all the items which are available in `old` from `original`, so I did:

```
original = original.filter(function(el) {
                    return old.indexOf(el) < 0;
                }.bind(this));
```

but I get the same items, what I did wrong?
Here is the code snippet.

```js
let original = [{
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "3"
  }
];

let old = [{
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "7"
  },
  {
    id: "9"
  }
];
console.log(original);

original = original.filter(function(el) {
  return old.indexOf(el) < 0;
}.bind(this));

console.log(original);
```

Comment: what is `this` doing? if needed you could use it as second parameter without binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/javascript-arrays-remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` cannot compare the contents of objects.

You need to check the `id`

```js
var original = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
  ],
  old = [
     { id: "1"},
     { id: "7"},
     { id: "9"}
  ];


original = original.filter(function(el) {
  return old.findIndex(item => item.id === el.id) < 0;
});

console.log(original);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var original = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
  ],
  old = [
     { id: "1"},
     { id: "7"},
     { id: "9"}
  ];

  var result = original.filter(function(obj) { return old.every(function(obj2) { return obj.id != obj2.id;}) });

console.log(result)
```

This will return: 2,3

Comment: this works only if the objects have the same reference to the objects with same `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with the unwanted `id` and filter the array.

```js
var array = [ { id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }],
    old = [{ id: "1" }, { id: "7" }, { id: "9" }],
    oldSet = new Set(old.map(({ id }) => id));
    
array = array.filter(({ id }) => !oldSet.has(id));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using filter and forEach

```js
var old=[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]


var original=[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "7"},
   { id: "9"}
]
var obj=[];
old.forEach((e)=>obj.push(e.id))
console.log(original.filter((e)=>!obj.includes(e.id)?true:false))
```