# How to clear selected row in v-data-table, Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vue app where I'm using `v-data-table` with `show-select` option. I want to clear only selected data using the "cancel" button. Already I can clear all data from the table onclick.

Example in picture: I want to clear only the selected row (Ice cream sandwich)

[image]

Here is my code:

Table:

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :single-select="singleSelect"
  item-key="name"
  show-select
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:top>
    <v-switch
      v-model="singleSelect"
      label="Single select"
      class="pa-3"
    ></v-switch>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

"cancel" button

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" color="primary" @click="cancel"> Cancel </v-btn>
```

script

```
cancel() {
   this.desserts = [];
},
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "clear"? Do you want to unselect the selection or delete it?

Comment: I want to unselect the selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to deselect them:

```js
cancel() {
   this.selected = [];
}
```

If you want to remove them:

```js
cancel() {
  this.desserts = this.desserts.filter(item => {
    return this.selected.indexOf(item) < 0;
  });
}
```

<sub>Keep in mind that this array subtraction algorithm is O(n^2) complexity, so for large datasets this may be slow.  In that case, you can use a [more robust algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array)</sub>