# Multiple filters for arrays - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have 3 arrays. I want to return the elements in array1 distinct from array2 and array3.
Example:

```
array1: ["Peter", "James", "JohnDoe", "Jackie"]
array2: ["James", "Dog"]
array3: ["JohnDoe", "Cat"]

Output: ["Peter", "Jackie"]
```

Here is my code snippet of filtering array2 out of array1.

```
  const array1, array2, array3;

  const result = array1.filter(
    element=> !array2.some(ele => element.id === ele.id)
  );
// Output: ["Peter", "JohnDoe", "Jackie"]
```

I can think of creating another const for filtering array3, but is there a better/elegant way to attach the filters together(in one statement)? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried something like res = array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item) && !array3.includes(item));

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this. Just add an `&& secondCondition`. I also took away the `id` accessors since the code didn't work with the examples you provided

```js
const array1 = ["Peter", "James", "JohnDoe", "Jackie"]
const array2 = ["James", "Dog"]
const array3 = ["JohnDoe", "Cat"]

const result = array1.filter(
  element => !array2.some(ele => element === ele) && !array3.some(ele => element === ele)
);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19957463/8478131