# 2D Array Object to 1D array filter function

Tags: javascript

**Use Case 1**
Assuming i have 2dArray Object of

```
let arr = [{'getName':'Report1'},{'getName':'User'},{'getName':'report 2'},{'getName':'User'},{'getName':'User'}]
let _NotRequiredSheet = ['User','Report 254',...]
```

Im trying to optimise my script with functional programming which will return me an array of

```
 ['report1','report2']
```

The current Method im using which does not have any error is :

```
 for(let i =0;i < arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i].getName != _NotRequiredSheet[0]){
                console.log(arr[i].getName)
            }
        }
```

But this will impact if _notrequiredSheet have a big list of what is not required

I tried using this approach which is using filter but since its 2dObject Array, im unsure how should this be implemented.
What i did on my poc is

```
    //Approach 1 : Not Working 
    let result = arr.filter(function (arr) {
        return arr.getName != _NotRequiredSheet.values();
    })

    //Output should be as 1dArray['report1','report2'] , not (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    console.log(result)



    //Approach 2 : Will output as 2D array with filtered value
    // Will require to hardcord the index which is not advisable
    let result = arr.filter(function (arr) {
        return arr.getName != _NotRequiredSheet[0];
    })
    console.log(result)
```

i wanted to check if there is any way i could pass on using for loop with filter function. Result should return as 1D array which is

['Report1','Report2']

**Use case 1 is Solved**

**Use Case 2 : 2D Object Array**
Assuming data is declared as

```
    let arr2 = [
        {$0:{'Name':'Report1'}},
        {$0:{'Name':'Report2'}},
        {$0:{'Name':'User'}}
    ]
```

Result should show this on console.log `(2) [{…}, {…}]`  , filter function will remove 'User' as its reflected in _NotRequiredSheet.

Using the syntax i wrote

```
let result = arr2.map(item => item.$0.Name).filter(Name => !_NotRequiredSheet.includes(Name))
```

This will return as a single array

Comment: First [map the objects to their property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array). Then [filter out the elements present in the other array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter your data with looking for unwanted values and map only the wanted property.

```js
const
    data = [{ getName: 'Report1' }, { getName: 'User' }, { getName: 'report 2' }, { getName: 'User' }, { getName: 'User' }],
    _NotRequiredSheet = ['User', 'Report 254'],
    result = data
        .filter(({ getName }) => !_NotRequiredSheet.includes(getName))
        .map(({ getName }) => getName);

console.log(result);
```

With a Set

```js
const
    data = [{ getName: 'Report1' }, { getName: 'User' }, { getName: 'report 2' }, { getName: 'User' }, { getName: 'User' }],
    _NotRequiredSheet = ['User', 'Report 254'],
    take = k => o => o[k],
    hasNot = s => v => !s.has(v),
    comp = f => g => o => f(g(o)),
    result = data
        .filter(
            comp(hasNot(new Set(_NotRequiredSheet)))(take('getName'))
        )
        .map(({ getName }) => getName);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: looks clean, but the complexity is still O(n*m)

Comment: try using `Set.has()` which has O(1)

Comment: Clean answer, will look into both set.has()

Comment: If in a  scenario data is declared as 2d object, `let data = [ {$0:{'Name':'Report1'}} ]` , using the method provided , .filter(({ $0.getName }) .... will result ',' is expected

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
so you can return something based on `_NotRequiredSheet.includes(cur.getName)`

```js
let arr = [{'getName':'Report1'},{'getName':'User'},{'getName':'report 2'},{'getName':'User'},{'getName':'User'}]
let _NotRequiredSheet = ['User','Report 254' ];

let res = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    if (_NotRequiredSheet.includes(cur.getName)) {
      return prev;
    } else {
      return [ ...prev, cur.getName ];
    }
}, []);
console.log(res);
```