# Filtering Two Arrays based on values to remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, filter

I have two arrays that I am trying to filter specific values from them. In **arr1** i have my intial dataset. in **arr2** I have the items I want to delete from **arr1**.

The data in **arr1** should only be deleted if it matches both the property's **arr2.item** and **arr2.itemID**

```
let arr1 = [
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8189', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8188', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Pear', itemID: '7144', pricePaid: 1.0483152 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '375', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
]


let arr2 = [
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374' },
]
```

The code that I tried before was

```
const filtered_arr = arr2.map(i => JSON.stringify(i.item, i.itemID));
const NewItems = arr1.filter(i => !filtered_arr.includes(JSON.stringify(i.item, i.itemID)));
console.log(NewItems);
```

However, I am not getting the correct output.

The output I am looking for is:

```
[
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8189', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8188', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Pear', itemID: '7144', pricePaid: 1.0483152 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '375', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
]
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: check this answer please it may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900750/4932219

Comment: Are you trying to remove items from `arr1` that match both the properties in each item of `arr2`?  Or just remove items that match the `itemID`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry i wasn't clear enough. Items in arr1 should only be removed if they match both properties in arr2. Just updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: `let res = arr1.filter((el) => !arr2.some((x) => x.item===el.item && x.itemID === el.itemID))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have a chance because:

```
JSON.stringify(i.item, i.itemID)
```

is not used correctly.  `JSON.stringify()` has a function signature like this:

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
```

You can't just pass it two pieces of data like you were.  You would have to combine those two pieces of data into an array or object before calling `JSON.stringify()` on that single object.  but, as you will see in my second solution below, you don't need JSON to make a canonical representation of the two values that is directly comparable.  Since they are both strings, you can just add them with a separator between them and then you can just directly compare the strings.

---

In my solutions to problems like this, I generally try to avoid NxM lookups when comparing multiple arrays by either using a `Map` or `Set` for more efficient lookup.  A few lines more code than brute force searching, but a lot more efficient if the arrays get larger.

Here's one way, using a `Map` object for efficient lookup:

```js
function filterArray(source, removals) {
    const removeMap = new Map(removals.map(entry => [entry.itemID, entry.item]));
    return source.filter(entry => {
        const match = removeMap.get(entry.itemID);
        return !match || match !== entry.item;
    });
}

let arr1 = [
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8189', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8188', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Pear', itemID: '7144', pricePaid: 1.0483152 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '375', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
]


let arr2 = [
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374' },
]

console.log(filterArray(arr1, arr2));
```

And, a slightly shorter version using a `Set` for efficient lookup that combines the item and itemID into a single canonical string in a `Set` object:

```js
function filterArray2(source, removals) {
    const removeSet = new Set(removals.map(entry => `${entry.item}-${entry.itemID}`));
    return source.filter(entry => !removeSet.has(`${entry.item}-${entry.itemID}`));
}

let arr1 = [
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8189', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8188', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Pear', itemID: '7144', pricePaid: 1.0483152 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '375', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
]


let arr2 = [
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374' },
]

console.log(filterArray2(arr1, arr2));
```

This version just assumes that an `itemID` can't start with a `-` and an item name can't end with a `-`.  If they could, then you just need a different separator character that isn't allowed at either the end of an item name or the start of an itemID.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr1 = [
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8189', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Apple', itemID: '8188', pricePaid: 0.0762235 },
  { item: 'Pear', itemID: '7144', pricePaid: 1.0483152 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '375', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374', pricePaid: 0.002027 },
]


let arr2 = [
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '378' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '377' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '376' },
  { item: 'Berry', itemID: '374' },
]
let arr3=[];
arr2.filter((ele,ind)=>{
    arr1.filter((ele2,ind2)=>{
        if(ele.item===ele2.item && ele.itemID===ele2.itemID){
            arr3.push(arr1[ind2]);
        }
    })
})
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: See your arr2 array is the comparing array and arr1 is the filter array , where we can remove arr2 elements if its arr2.item and arr2.itemID. So i took arr2 as parrent array and arr1 as need to do filterration and thats all