# remove sepcific items from array of strings javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an array that is

`const arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]`

I need to exclude a,b that is I need. How to achieve this in fastest possible way

`["c","d","e"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all elements contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if I understand it correctly

```
arr.filter((value) => value != 'a' && value != 'b')
```

gives below output

```
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: This is exactly what the answers of the duplicate question already explain. There is no reason to explain it again on a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Using array.filter() we can do it.
like:

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
arr.filter(x => x !== 'a'); // output: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

But if you want to remove a group of items then use another array and use validation with in `filter()` function.

Example:

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
removeItems = ['a', 'b'];
arr.filter(x => removeItems.indexOf(x) < 0); // ['c', 'd', 'e']
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what the answers of the duplicate question already explain. There is no reason to explain it again on a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 1 line using spread operator

```
   const [one,two,three,...rest]=arr;

   console.log(rest); // it prints d,e excluding a,b,c.
```

Comment: solution must be  more dynamic , instead of static solution.