# Difference between two arrays in Angular JS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Consider following arrays:

```
array1 = ['a','b'];
array2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

I need to extract the difference. So my resulting array should look something like,

```
array3 = ['c','d'];
```

If an element is present in array1 then it should be poped from array2.
I am looking for solutions more angular way,is there any directive available?

Comment: There is a plain JavaScript answer available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669555/javascript-remove-array-from-array: `var c = array2.filter(function(item) { return array1.indexOf(item) === -1; });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can use underscore or lodash library for such tasks.
for example in underscore you can done it through this simple code :

> difference_.difference(array, *others)

Similar to without, but returns the values from array that are not present in the other arrays.

_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
=> [1, 3, 4]

[underscore annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html)